# Select stores who have this product(mysql query)

Tags: mysql

I have two tables, stores and products. I need a way of querying where i could get all the stores, who have this product and the "is_available" column is equal to yes.

```
stores
>id
>name
>description

products
>id
>store_id(FK)
>name
>price
>is_available(yes or no)
```

Comment: Some advice: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: 'each users have one store' - many users can have same store?

Comment: I think "each users have one store" is a wrong explanation

Comment: @yusufhayırsever, each "user have one store" sorry

Comment: Maybe it is vendor not user?

Comment: @yusufhayırsever, you can call it like that also, in my case user have options where he can be a vendor or a courier

Comment: If every user has only one  store, you don't need 3 tables. Keep one id at the same table, keep store name and user name etc. as columns. you only need 2 tables. Then the other things will be so easy.

Comment: there are some instances, where user dont have a store, for example if they are a courier

Comment: You need another table and you have to keep in this table user type(like courier, vendor etc. İnt store table which kind of information you will keep. Can you give an example?

Comment: @yusufhayırsever, i have updated my posts, hope it is a lot clearer now